# Is there a term for an amateur bicycle rider in French?

Tags: demande-de-mot

I saw this nice picture of the President of France, and recalled a term we Russians use for a bicyclist who only rides small distances in the city: "flowerbed rider" (клумбокат). I would not call it derisive, it has a nice amateurish touch to it. A lot of people call themselves "flowerbed riders". There has been a bicycle craze in Russia in the last several years.

I'm curious if there's a similar term in French.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really. If someone only cycle for small distances to go to work for instance they won't call themselves cyclist.
Someone who goes cycling every once in a while are called

> Cycliste du dimanche (sunday cyclist)

There are also sunday runners, walkers ...

Comment: Despite Sunday being the day most people don't work.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps I understood *cycliste du dimanche* as one of those who only goes infrequently, not commuting daily.

Comment: @LukeSawczak And you were right, I was kidding.

Answer (score 2):

"Cycliste du dimanche" convient ainsi que le terme "pratiquant du vélo".
Le terme "vélophile" existe aussi mais est inusité.